# How can I combine both of my methods to just one method?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, methods, command-line-interface

I'm making a guitar browsing cli project. I have two categories `Electric` and `Acoustic`.
I have made 2 methods for both of the categories: `mass_create_electrics` and `mass_create_acoustics`

```
@@electrics = []
@@acoustics = []

def self.electrics
    @@electrics
end

def self.acoustics
    @@acoustics
end

def self.mass_create_electrics(electric_hash)
    electric_hash.each do |e_hash|
        electric = HiStrung::Guitar.new(e_hash[:name], e_hash[:url])
        @@electrics << electric
    end
end

def self.mass_create_acoustics(acoustic_hash)
    acoustic_hash.each do |a_hash|
        acoustic = HiStrung::Guitar.new(a_hash[:name], a_hash[:url])
        @@acoustics << acoustic
    end
end
```

As you can see, both of the methods are doing the same thing, so my objective is to make only 1 method that instantiates both electric and acoustic guitars. Here's the checklist for what I am supposed to do.

- Create a .mass_create_guitars method in your Guitar class that takes in 2 arguments 
  (a guitar hash and the guitar category)
- The method should be able to be used to instantiate both electric guitars 
  and acoustic guitars
- The 2nd argument will determine whether or not 
  the guitars are added to your collection of @@electrics or your collection of @@acoustics
- This method should replace both the mass_create_electrics and mass_create_acoustics 
  so that you no longer will have 2 methods doing almost the same thing.

So here's the method I have so far:

```
def self.mass_create_guitars(guitar_hash, category)
    guitar_hash.each do |g_hash|
        guitars = HiStrung::Guitar.new(g_hash[:name], g_hash[:url])

    end
end
```

But I am unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two differences between the two methods are:

- the hash that the guitars are pulled *from*
- the array that the guitars are pushed *to*

So, these two things should be the parameters. The hash already is a parameter, so all you need to do is to add the array as a second parameter:

```rb
def self.mass_create_guitars(guitar_hash, guitar_array)
  guitar_hash.each do |guitar|
    guitar_array << HiStrung::Guitar.new(guitar_hash[:name], guitar_hash[:url])
  end
end

def self.mass_create_electrics(electric_hash)
  mass_create_guitars(electric_hash, electrics)
end

def self.mass_create_acoustics(acoustic_hash)
  mass_create_guitars(acoustic_hash, acoustics)
end
```

By the way, `electric_hash` and `acoustic_hash` are strange names, because they are clearly not hashes, they look more like arrays.